# ffmpeg is not installed in my docker container

Tags: ffmpeg, dockerfile, containers

I have write below commands in my Dockerfile, for installing `ffmpeg` in a docker container.

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ffmpeg
```

While I'm building my Dockerfile it will show me ffmpeg install in my image, when i run my image as a container and manually enter in that image it will show me `ffmpeg` command is not found.

Can you please help me on this?